# Python Compare lists

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, mysql-connector-python

So I have this script,

```
good_users=[]

async def callposts(ctx):
    g0=str(ctx.guild)
    g=g0.replace(' ','_')
    sqluse(g)
    x="SELECT authorid, COUNT(*) FROM posts GROUP BY authorid"
    mycursor.execute(x)
    k=mycursor.fetchall()
    for user in k:
        if user[1] > 7:
            good_users.append(user)
            k.remove(user)
            print(user)
    return k

async def kick(ctx, uid):
    await ctx.guild.kick(ctx.guild.get_member(int(uid)))



@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def post_check(ctx):
    ausers=list(ctx.guild.members)
    lowposters= await callposts(ctx)
    for user in ausers:
        if user == client.user:
            print(user.name+" is a bot!")
            ausers.remove(user)
        elif user.id in exempt:
            print(user.name+" is exempt!")
            ausers.remove(user)
        elif user.id in good_users:
            print(user.name+" is a good user!")
            ausers.remove(user)
        else:
            await kick(ctx,user.id)
    print(ausers)
```

What I am trying to do here is remove inactive users. So I have 2 lists that I want to compare the memberlist to, exempt and good_users. I also am checking to make sure it isn't the bot. So this script removes the bot from the list but it doesn't remove the user that's in exempt or good users. So in turn it tries to kick everyone that's not a bot.  *They are trying to take over!*

I'm looking this over but right now I'm sick so not 100%.

The prints are just for troubleshooting purposes however, all but the firt print in the callpost function print nothing and that one for some reason only prints the user, now it isn't printing the bot so the bot may not be in the list to get removed.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured this out, the script was looking at user.id as an attribute of user object. To fix that I had to use

```
elif str(user.id) in exempt): and elif str(user.id) in good_users:
```

Answer (score 0):

You're never appending anything to `exempt_users` and because of the scope of `good_users` it is only filled with users within `callposts()` because you're not returning it when calling it in `post_check()`.

Changing the following should fix your problem:

- Return good_users from callposts()
- Add a new variable to where you call callposts() in post_check() like

```
lowposters, good_users = await callposts(ctx)
```

Comment: Good users is outside the function so shouldn’t need to be returned should it? Also, it’s just a redundancy. The function appends good_users and removes the user from k in the if statement. Ultimately the kick list is k so anyone removed from it shouldn’t get kicked. Also exempt is a hard coded list of exempt users such as myself.

Comment: You're right, the scope should be fine. You're not kicking people from k though, but from all the guild members. ```for user in ausers:```

Comment: You’re right! It needs another for statement ... for item in k then kick

Comment: So, I'm at my computer now and have reviewed the script more in depth with our conversation in mind. It seems this is still not the solution. ausers (short for allusers is supposed to be a list of all the users in the guild so every user is supposed to be kicked unless they are in the good users list or the exempt list. the callposts function should add any users that need to be added to the good users list and exempt is a hard coded list. The if,elif and else statements including the kick statement are under a for statement. for each user in all users if they are in those list remove or kick.